# Java LinkedList of bufferedImages staying all the same

Tags: java

I am currently working through creating an object that contains 12 sprites in total. Each list is defined below inside of the main list, spriteList.
 My problem is that when going through all the files in the directory each image that I grab is set for every index in that list. 
For some reason it goes by which file appears first. Anyone know why, am I making a permanent reference somewhere?

```
public class EntitySprites {
   //A list containing 4 linkedlist, the first one is for up sprites, second is for right
   //third is for down, 4th is for left. Each sub list contains 3 sprites, at index 0 is the standing or idle
   //sprite, the first corespond to the first frame of the walking animation and the 2nd index is for the 
   //2nd frame of animation

   LinkedList<LinkedList<BufferedImage>> spriteList;

   public EntitySprites(String path) {
      File directory = new File(path);
      spriteList = new LinkedList<LinkedList<BufferedImage>>();

      LinkedList<BufferedImage> temp;

      for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
         spriteList.add(new LinkedList<BufferedImage>());
      }

      BufferedImage ret = null;
      for(File f : directory.listFiles()) {
         String fName = f.getName();

         //Filters out all sprites that do not corespond to a walking or standing 
         if(fName.indexOf("walk") != -1 || fName.indexOf("stand") != -1) {


            try {
               ret = ImageIO.read(f);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();

            }
            spriteList.get(getDirect(fName)).add(ret);
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: What does `getDirect(...)` do? Learn [how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Notice that you create a new instance of spritList each time you call this function.

Comment: @Jesper getDirect returns an integer that correspond to the direction at which the sprite is going towards, I've tested the code it gets the right images the list is just not containing the write images at each direction.  this is a constructor so it only gets called upon instantiation of a EntitySprites object

Comment: You should probably move this line `spriteList.get(getDirect(fName)).add(ret);` into the try block

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the `LinkedList`  contains only the last image grabbed. 
The reason is that you fill the list with a reference : `BufferedImage ret`, and change the 
reference after it was added. 
In other words it is [mutable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mutable):

> A variable having a value that is changeable during program execution

Creating a new reference each time you update the `LinkedList` by 
moving `BufferedImage ret = null;` inside the `for(File f : directory.listFiles())` loop 
 Or

```
try {
     spriteList.get(getDirect(fName)).add(ImageIO.read(f));
} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

should solve it.